# Expectation property of martingales

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales, expected-value

Suppose $(Y_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is a martingale of discrete random variables.

Put $A:= \{(Y_0, \dots, Y_{n-1}) = (y_0, \dots, y_{n-1})\}$

In a proof I'm reading, it is claimed that

$$\mathbb{E}[Y_nY_{n-1}I_A] = y_{n-1} \mathbb{E}[Y_nI_A] = y_{n-1}^2 \mathbb{P}(A)$$

What property of martingales is used here?

Comment: Do you know the tower property?

Comment: Yes, I do? Is it relevant here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${E}[Y_nY_{n-1}I_A] = {E}[Y_nY_{n-1} | A]P(A) =
{E}[Y_nY_{n-1}| Y_{n-1}= y_{n-1}]P(A)=\\ 
y_{n-1} E[Y_{n}|Y_{n-1}= y_{n-1}]P(A)=y_{n-1}^2P(A)
$$

The first equality is from the definition of conditional expectation and the third from the basic martingale property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why is the second equality true?

Comment: In general, that's called 'taking out what is known' or 'pull-out' property of expectation.

Comment: Thanks. This helped a great deal!